# Apex upgrade from 5.1.4 to 18.1 issue

Tags: oracle

Just upgraded from 5.1.4 to 18.1 on 12c and get this message when the homepage loads:

> There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files are not up-to-date! The files for version 5.1.4.00.08 have been loaded, but 18.1.0.00.45 is expected. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide.

Well, but I ran the command: apxldimg.sql
So, what can be the solution to this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did `apxldimg.sql` end successfully?

Comment: Are your using the embedded gateway or ORDS ?  If the latter, then the files are physically on the OS, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So browser force refresh helped. Ctrl - F5
My mistake was, that I loaded the homepage before I ran `apxldimg.sql`, but with no error, by the way.
Thank you guys for your comments.

Answer (score -2):

Please check my post from here:

https://github.com/wfg2513148/cn-oracle-apex/tree/master/how-to-upgrade-oracle-apex-from-5.1.4-to-18.1